# QtDesigner being overzealous with HTML tags when formatting as richtext?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

In plain code, a `QLabel` can be made bold by something as simple as:

```
myLabel = QtGui.QLabel("<strong>My bold label!</strong>")
```

However, QtDesigner insists on using:

```
myLabel = QLabel('<html><head/><body><p><span style=" font-weight:600;">My bold label!</span></p></body></html>')
```

Is this actually necessary, or is it another case of a WYSIWYG editor being massively overzealous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra markup will only be added if you use the Rich Text tab of the editing dialog. Your own markup will be preserved verbatim if you:

- directly edit the label (i.e. via double-click or pressing F2)
- add it to the line-edit of the **text** property
- use the Source tab of the editing dialog

**EDIT**:

To answer the question of whether the full markup is strictly *necessary*: no, not really. According to the Qt docs on the [Supported HTML Subset](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html), it is compliant with the HTML 4 spec. So, as with any reasonably competent html-rendering engine, it should have no difficulty dealing with an html document containing only the fragment `<strong>My bold label!</strong>`.

Comment: Yeah - sorry, I had observed that behaviour. I just didn't know if there was anything in the docs which said that the the full extended markup was actually strictly correct

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't know how WYSIWYG editors are usually written, but I imagine it would complicate things horribly if you had to special-case everything in an attempt to minimise the markup. So it probably works the way it does because that is just the simplest way to do things, and nobody ever found the enthusiasm to optimise it any further (and who can blame them).

Comment: You're almost certainly correct - Dreamweaver does a fairly good job of creating HTML, but (old) versions of MS Word created hundreds of lines of seemingly redundant code for what could be a 1 line webpage... I guess what I was asking here is if just having `myLabel = QtGui.QLabel("<strong>My bold label!</strong>")` was actually incorrect, and I guess the answer is no!

Comment: @ChrisW. Probably I didn't read your question literally enough. I've added a bit to my answer that hopefully gives a more definitive statement.